# How can I exclude a specific string from a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have the following rule to match any website that begins with two numbers:

`([0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+)+(\.net|\.com)`

It matches domains like:

`99abc.com`
`78c.net`

How can I exclude from this rule a list of specific websites, for example

`10ofthose.com`
`180post.net`
etc...?

Comment: You mean you want to exclude addresses that has more than 2 numbers at the beginning of the string? Or do you want to exclude only those 2 addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could a negative lookahead blacklist to the start of the pattern:

```
^(?!(?:10ofthose\.com|180post\.net)$)[0-9]{2}[a-z]+\.(?:net|com)$
```

### Demo